# matches() matching words that must start with capitals in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

So, I've been working with using the method 'matches()' in Java.. as in:

```
Str1 = 'Jane';
Str1.matches("[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*");
```

to find whether a string starts with a capital and is followed by any number of big/small letters. I can seem to figure out all the configurations except when I'm trying to match an unknown amount of words. For example if I want to confirm a string is made up of just letters and spaces where each word starts with a capital letter. I was thinking could do

```
Str2 = 'Jane Marie Doe';
Str2.matches("[A-Z][a-zA-Z\\s]*");
```

as in a capital followed by any number of spaces, capitals, and lower cases but that wouldn't enforce the rule that every space had to be followed by a capital. Do I need to tokenize(not sure if that's the right word) or split my string up using the spaces as delimiters and then evaluate each word? Or is there a way to enter this into the matches method sort of like ([A-Z][a-zA-Z]\\s)* where the asterisk means any number of the entire entry in parenthesis? Though as I'm typing this I'm thinking that won't even conceptually work because the last word won't have a space after it. Perhaps ([A-Z][a-zA-Z]\\s?)* would work? But, it doesn't. Is there something that will?

I did see that there were some other questions that addressed this but I couldn't seem to find a definitive working answer.

Comment: `([A-Z][a-zA-Z]*\s*)*` seems to me like it'd work

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt, if there's always only one space between words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
([A-Z][a-zA-Z]*\s*)+
```

Single capital letter, followed by any number of other letters, followed by any number of spaces, repeated any number of times.

Depending on your situation, you might also want to add in legal punctuation, like hyphens and stuff.

So, something like:

```
([A-Z][a-zA-Z\-\']*\s*)*
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
"([A-Z][a-zA-Z]*\\s*)*"
```

I just changed `\\s?` to `\\s*` to allow matching of more than one space between words.

Comment: Wont work. That matches a capital, plus a single other letter, plus any number of spaces

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt Oops. Fixed.

Comment: Now it matches mine from the comment, though :P

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt - Well +1 to your solution. :) (I honestly didn't see your comment when I started composing my answer or when I reacted to your comment. The missing `*` was because I copied the wrong expression from OP's original post.)

Comment: @TedHopp I will never be opposed to an answer similar to one of mine if I get an upvote out of it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regex:

```
"[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*(\\s+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*)*$"
```

Comment: Won't work. That matches a 2 letter capital word, followed by any other number of 2 letter words. This would match a document full of 2 letter words.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt: Thanks for spotting the typo.

Comment: Still don't quite understand. That regex would match a whole document, provided it didn't contain any punctuation.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt: Not sure I follow. Could you provide a specific string on which you think it would not behave as it should?

Comment: `"Hello Look I Am A String Which Contains No Punctuation Causing It To Look Like It Was Written By A Fourth Grader But It Does Serve To Illustrate The Point"`

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt: That's valid input, is it not? Or am I misreading the question?

Comment: Well, yes, but I think he only wants to match individual words, right? Yours would match the whole string of words.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt: The question says *I want to confirm a string is made up of just letters and spaces where each word starts with a capital letter*. This regex would confirm that.

Comment: Shhh and let me go back to sleep!

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt: No worries :)

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
^([A-Z][a-zA-Z]*\s*)+$
```